# Python - how to get the current weekday without using calendar, datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime, calendar

I'm having a little bit of a problem here. My system lets me

> pip install calendar

but for some reason it doesn't recognize it when importing it in my script.

Whereas for `datetime`, the module **datetime.datetime** gives me an error saying that

> there is no attribute datetime in datetime.

And **datetime.date** wants me to feed it a `datetime.datetime` object, therefore it doesn't let me input strings, lists, ints, or whatever.

Does anyone know another **possible way to get the current weekday**, or how to **fix one of the above**?

Thanks

Comment: Please post a minimal code if you want to ge help

Comment: I did, it's down below

Answer (score 0):

using `time`.

```
from time import time, localtime, strftime

x=localtime(time())
strftime("%A",x) # 'Tuesday'
```

Comment: Thanks, it's an interesting way, but apparently it messes with another line in my code
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/...", line 309, in <module>
    strings = time.strftime('%H, %M, %S')
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: @NiccolòDiana are you python2?

Comment: Im using the 3.6.5 version

Comment: @NiccolòDiana could you add you code got error? I'm confused now.

Comment: I commented it below, with an example of the code and the error given

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your most recent errors are caused by the same thing causing the original error with the `datetime` module.

> there is no attribute datetime in datetime.

Is likely the same as the error caused by this line `hoursMinsSecs = time.strftime('%H, %M, %S')`

These errors are caused because both the datetime and time modules have objects with the same name as the module. (time.time and datetime.datetime). Therefore, *how you import the modules or objects* becomes very important.

In the `time` example, your import statement is:

```
from time import time, localtime, strftime
```

As a result, the time *object* has been imported into your namespace and not the time *module*. Therefore, when you try to run `time.strftime('%H, %M, %S')` you get an error that strftime isn’t an attribute of the time object.

Instead, since you already imported strftime, just call that directly and do not qualify it with time. (i.e. `strftime('%H, %M, %S')`)

For your datetime example, you probably had the import statement `from datetime import datetime`, but somewhere in your code used `datetime.datetime`